# Owl Carousel loop last item back to first item

Tags: javascript, html, owl-carousel-2

I am using owl carousel v2.2.0 for a list of projects on my website. After the carousel scrolls to the last item it stays there. I would like it to loop back to the first item and keep looping instead of stopping at last item.
I tried changing loop: false to true but that did nothing.
This is my code:

```
Owl.Defaults = {
        items: 3,
        loop: false,
        center: false,
        rewind: false,

        mouseDrag: true,
        touchDrag: true,
        pullDrag: true,
        freeDrag: false,

        margin: 0,
        stagePadding: 0,

        merge: false,
        mergeFit: true,
        autoWidth: false,

        startPosition: 0,
        rtl: false,

        smartSpeed: 250,
        fluidSpeed: false,
        dragEndSpeed: false,

        responsive: {},
        responsiveRefreshRate: 200,
        responsiveBaseElement: window,

        fallbackEasing: 'swing',

        info: false,

        nestedItemSelector: false,
        itemElement: 'div',
        stageElement: 'div',

        refreshClass: 'owl-refresh',
        loadedClass: 'owl-loaded',
        loadingClass: 'owl-loading',
        rtlClass: 'owl-rtl',
        responsiveClass: 'owl-responsive',
        dragClass: 'owl-drag',
        itemClass: 'owl-item',
        stageClass: 'owl-stage',
        stageOuterClass: 'owl-stage-outer',
        grabClass: 'owl-grab'
    };
```

and this is the html:

```
<!--Project Section-->
    <section class="project-section-three">
      <div class="auto-container">
          <!--Sec Title-->
            <div class="sec-title light">
              <h2>Latest Projects</h2>
                <div class="separator"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="three-item-carousel owl-carousel owl-theme">

                <!--Project Block Four-->
                <div class="project-block-four">
                  <div class="inner-box">
                      <div class="image">
                          <a href="projects/project-1.html"><img src="images/resource/project-1.jpg" alt="" /></a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="lower-content">
                          <h3><a href="projects/project-1.html">US Gas Company</a></h3>
                            <div class="text">Teachings of the great explorer of the truth, builder of human happiness.</div>
                            <a href="projects/project-1.html" class="read-more">Read More <span class="icon flaticon-arrow-pointing-to-right"></span></a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>       
                <!--Project Block Four-->
                <div class="project-block-four">
                  <div class="inner-box">
                      <div class="image">
                          <a href="projects/project-4.html"><img src="images/resource/project-6.jpg" alt="" /></a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="lower-content">
                          <h3><a href="projects/project-4.html">Golden Gate Bridge</a></h3>
                            <div class="text">Except to obtain some advantage from it? But who has any right to find fault.</div>
                            <a href="projects/project-4.html" class="read-more">Read More <span class="icon flaticon-arrow-pointing-to-right"></span></a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <!--Project Block Four-->
                <div class="project-block-four">
                  <div class="inner-box">
                      <div class="image">
                          <a href="projects/project-4.html"><img src="images/resource/project-6.jpg" alt="" /></a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="lower-content">
                          <h3><a href="projects/project-4.html">Golden Gate Bridge</a></h3>
                            <div class="text">Except to obtain some advantage from it? But who has any right to find fault.</div>
                            <a href="projects/project-4.html" class="read-more">Read More <span class="icon flaticon-arrow-pointing-to-right"></span></a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <!--Project Block Four-->
                <div class="project-block-four">
                  <div class="inner-box">
                      <div class="image">
                          <a href="projects/project-4.html"><img src="images/resource/project-6.jpg" alt="" /></a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="lower-content">
                          <h3><a href="projects/project-4.html">Golden Gate Bridge</a></h3>
                            <div class="text">Except to obtain some advantage from it? But who has any right to find fault.</div>
                            <a href="projects/project-4.html" class="read-more">Read More <span class="icon flaticon-arrow-pointing-to-right"></span></a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <!--Project Block Four-->
                <div class="project-block-four">
                  <div class="inner-box">
                      <div class="image">
                          <a href="projects/project-4.html"><img src="images/resource/project-6.jpg" alt="" /></a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="lower-content">
                          <h3><a href="projects/project-4.html">Golden Gate Bridge</a></h3>
                            <div class="text">Except to obtain some advantage from it? But who has any right to find fault.</div>
                            <a href="projects/project-4.html" class="read-more">Read More <span class="icon flaticon-arrow-pointing-to-right"></span></a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
    <!--End Project Section-->
```

Comment: I'm not proficient with Owl Carousel, but have you tried setting the `rewind` property to true?

Comment: can you check this working example for [Owl Carousel](https://codepen.io/washaweb/pen/KVRxRW)  might help you. I have work only on `flex slider` and `slick slider`

Comment: Thank you, setting rewind true worked. But I'm wondering now if it is possible to make it loop so that when you press next after the last item it continues scrolling right (like an infinite loop) and shows the first item, rather than scrolling left (rewinding) back to the first.

Comment: Is this what you want to do? [Autoplay Demo](https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/demos/autoplay.html) The latest version (2.3.4) has a new feature called Infinity Loop which gives it this effect. [Loop option](http://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/docs/api-options.html#loop)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example with some settings that might help

```
$("#owl-demo").owlCarousel({
  autoPlay: 3000, //Set AutoPlay to 3 seconds
  items : (enter your number of slides),
  rewindNav:false //**This

});
```

This is obviously jQuery, but you should be able to add `autoPlay` with an interval into your `Owl.Defaults` list, then change `rewind` to `rewindNav:false`. This should get you a seamless autoplay.

Comment: So do I need to change 'items: 3' to 4? Because I have 4 slides? And is autoplay in v2.2.2?

Comment: Yes, that should match how many slides you have. I believe it should be in v2.2.2, yes, but it may be smart to update to the current version (v2.3.4) right now anyway.

Answer (score 1):

**For Information:**

https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/docs/api-options.html

```
$('#owl-demo').owlCarousel({
    loop: false,
    rewind: true
});
```